# Bootstrap3 изменение сетки при уменьшении экрана

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

Есть сетка 5х3 при обычном разрешении.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="img/brand-art.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-km.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-linc.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-school.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-sonet.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="img/brand-tukzar.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-silwerhof.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-hatber.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-brauberg.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-ek.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="img/brand-berlingo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-stamm.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-stabilo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-gamma.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
                <img src="img/brand-luch.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

При уменьшении размера экрана < 992px, необходимо переделать сетку в 3х5, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю для твоей задачи подойдет такой вариант, всё заносится в один row, и пишется что-то типа:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-half-offset">
   <img src="img/brand-gamma.png" alt="">
</div>
```

так как сетка нацело на 5 столбцов не делится, можно к последнему элементу строки добавить:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2 col-half-offset">
   <img src="img/brand-gamma.png" alt="">
</div>
```

В итоге должна получиться такая структура:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-art.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-km.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-linc.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-school.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
        <img src="img/brand-sonet.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-tukzar.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-silwerhof.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-hatber.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-brauberg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
        <img src="img/brand-ek.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-berlingo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-stamm.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-stabilo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/brand-gamma.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
        <img src="img/brand-luch.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему-то при уменьшении сначала встает в 4 столбца, потом все в 1

Comment: Добавил пример, у тебя так получается?

Comment: да, но вместо col-lg-offset-2 я использую для каждого элемента col-half-offset

Comment: не пользовался никогда раньше col-half-offset

Comment: это мой кастомный класс делающий margin-left:1.495727%